# Failed to compare images, one from a UIButton

Tags: swift, uibutton

I know how to get the image of a button, but it doesn't seem to work here:

```
@IBAction func checkButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.image(for: .normal) == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "btn_check_off_normal_holo_light") {
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "btn_check_on_focused_holo_light").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    } else {
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "btn_check_off_normal_holo_light").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "UserCell"

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? UsersTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of SelectTableViewCell.")
    }

    cell.checkButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "btn_check_off_normal_holo_light").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    return cell
}
```

I set the button image in `cellForRowAt`(the button is in a cell in a dynamic tableview. In the simulator, I can see that the image **is** being set. However, this piece of code doesn't run:

```
if sender.image(for: .normal) == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "btn_check_off_normal_holo_light") {
    sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "btn_check_on_focused_holo_light").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
}
```

Setting a breakpoint tells me that Xcode skips right over the code inside the `if` statement: even though the image clearly has been set to the one in the `if` statement.

I wonder if I am missing something really simple here?

Comment: So your issue isn't getting the image. Your issue is attempting to compare the button's image to a new `UIImage` instance.

Comment: Yeah...I guess so...oops, maybe I should edit my question. @rmaddy

Comment: FYI - the use of a `guard` and `fatalError` is kind of pointless in your `cellForRowAt`. Just do a force-cast with no guard. You get a crash either way but with a lot less code.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for the information. I'll edit my code in Xcode, but the question is fine for now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general approach here is incorrect. Instead of attempting to check the button's current image as a way to toggle the image, you should have a flag as part of your data model used to populate the table view.

This flag is needed in your `cellForRowAt` so you know which image to show on each cell (cells get reused as you scroll).

Then your `checkButtonClicked` should simply toggle the flag for the given row and then tell the table view to reload that one row.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know why my old code wasn't working?

Comment: Because comparing `UIImage` instances doesn't actually compare the image data, just the pointer.

Comment: Then how *do* you compare the actual images?

Comment: You could get the PNG data representation and compare the `Data` instances I suppose.